# Не создавая объект в ООП

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Создал класс для работы с tpl - типа шаблонизатор.
После этого создаю объект, всё работает, замена проходит удачно и выдаёт результат. Моя задача это разобраться почему я не могу обратится к методу этого класса из другого файла, что бы сделать замену ещё раз.
Например:

```
$tpl = New tpl("main.tpl");
тут подключаются модули
$tpl -> display();
```

А в модулях подключаемых я пишу так:

```
$tpl -> set("{content}", "Контент");
```

Возникает ошибка:

> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in

То есть не создан объект.
Но я в предыдущем проекте своё делал точно так же и всё работает до сих пор без ошибок, а в этом не хочет.

Либо подскажите, как можно получить ранее заменённый tpl, что бы в подключаемых модулях можно было провести замену ещё раз?

Comment: где вы создаете `$tpl = New tpl("main.tpl");`? может в другом файле видимость отключена,пробовали `GLOBALS`?

Comment: У меня подключен __autoload видимость везде есть. А GLOBALS не хочу использовать, потому что он отходит уже.

Comment: тогда найдите такое же переменное, может быть так, что 2 переменные с одинаковыми названиями

Comment: Переменные не переносятся в другие подключаемые файлы

Answer (score 4):

Причин может быть две.

Во-первых, переменная есть, но не является нужным объектом. Это может происходить потому что объект не создался, или был уничтожен, или перезаписан. Для проверки этого надо вывести `var_dump($tpl)`.

Второй причиной может быть [отсутствие видимости переменной](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php). Для проверки этого варианта надо убедиться, что включен вывод *всех* ошибок, и ловить нотис undefined variable. Автолоад к этой проблеме отношения не имеет, поскольку он занимается созданием классов, а не их использованием. К ООП проблема видимости переменных также не имеет отношения.

Отдельно замечу, что такого рода шаблонизатор, с простой заменой токенов на текст, является абсолютно нежизнеспособным. Логика отображения включает в себя все основные детали машины Тьюринга. И просто заменой там не обойтись.

Comment: var_dump($tpl); - возвращает NULL в подключаемых...
А на счёт шаблонизатора, то я хотел сделать как в DLE сделано.
Что бы для обычных верстальщиков было понятно и удобно верстать шаблоны для движка, а если будет конструкции с php, то не всякий поймёт.

Comment: Значит есть косяк с видимостью переменной. Не передали вы её куда следует.
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php